# How to use fminsearch to find local maximum?

Tags: matlab, fminsearch

I would like to use fminsearch in order to find the local maximum of a function.

Is it possible to find local maximum using fminsearch with "just" searching on the negative return value of the function.

for example:

```
function f = myfun(x,a)
f = x(1)^2 + a*x(2)^2;
a = 1.5;
x = fminsearch(@(x) -1 * myfun(x,a),[0,1]);
```

Is it possible?

**Update1:** In order to elaborate my question and making it clearer (following some comments below) - I'm adding this update:

By asking if it's possible to do so, I meant  is it a proper use of `fminsearch` function - is it the intended use to find max using `fminsearch`?

**Update2:** for who ever concern with the same question - In addition to the correct answer below , here is the documentation from https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/optimizing-nonlinear-functions.html#bsgpq6p-10

> Maximizing Functions
>   The fminbnd and fminsearch solvers attempt to minimize an objective function. If you have a maximization problem, that is, a problem of the form
>
> max x f(x), then define g(x) = –f(x), and minimize g.
>
> For example, to find the maximum of `tan(cos(x))` near x = 5, evaluate:
>
> `[x fval] = fminbnd(@(x)-tan(cos(x)),3,8)`
>
> `x = 6.2832`
>
> `fval =    -1.5574`
>
> The maximum is 1.5574 (the negative of the reported
>   fval), and occurs at x = 6.2832. This answer is correct since, to five
>   digits, the maximum is tan(1) = 1.5574, which occurs at x = 2π =
>   6.2832.

Comment: Yes you can, that's also why there is no fmaxsearch function !

Comment: What do you mean is it possible? Did you run your code? If so did it work? If not then what was the error? If it did work then what are you asking?

Comment: I mean - is it a proper use of fminsearch - is it the intended use to find max using fminsearch?

Comment: @DeJaVo Yes. That is the accepted way to find the maximum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, that's also why there is no fmaxsearch function:

For example:

```
func = @(x) sin(x);

sol = fminsearch(@(x) func(x),0)
% sol = pi/2
sol = fminsearch(@(x) func(x)*-1,0)
% sol = -pi/2
```